# Sympy: drop terms with small coefficients

Tags: python, sympy, coefficients

Is it possible to drop terms with coefficients below a given, small number (say 1e-5) in a Sympy expression? I.e., such that

```
0.25 + 8.5*exp(-2.6*u) - 2.7e-17*exp(-2.4*u) + 1.2*exp(-0.1*u)
```

becomes

```
0.25 + 8.5*exp(-2.6*u) + 1.2*exp(-0.1*u)
```

for instance.

Comment: yes with as_ordered_terms you can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `coeffs`, `subs` and `Poly`:

```
u = Symbol('u')
poly = Poly(0.25 + 8.5*exp(-2.6*u) - 2.7e-17*exp(-2.4*u) + 1.2*exp(-0.1*u))
threshold = 1e-5

to_remove = [abs(i) for i in poly.coeffs() if abs(i) < threshold]
for i in to_remove:
    poly = poly.subs(i, 0)
```

`poly` no yields the following:

```
0.25 + 8.5*exp(-2.6*u) + 1.2*exp(-0.1*u)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that: extract the numbers from the expression, select the ones with absolute value lower than some threshold, build a substitution dictionary to set them to zero:

```py
expr = 0.25 + 8.5*exp(-2.6*u) - 2.7e-17*exp(-2.4*u) + 1.2*exp(-0.1*u)
small_numbers = set([e for e in expr.atoms(Number) if abs(e) < 1e-05])
d = {s: 0 for s in small_numbers}
expr.subs(d)
# out: 0.25 + 8.5*exp(-2.6*u) + 1.2*exp(-0.1*u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can filter out terms with coefficient smaller than a specified threshold using `as_ordered_terms`

Here is some code as example:

```
import sympy as sp

u = sp.Symbol('u')
expr = 0.25 + 8.5*sp.exp(-2.6*u) - 2.7e-17*sp.exp(-2.4*u) + 1.2*sp.exp(-0.1*u)
threshold = 1e-5

terms = expr.as_ordered_terms()
filtered_terms = [term for term in terms if abs(term.as_coefficient(u)) > threshold]
new_expr = sp.Add(*filtered_terms)

print(new_expr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately the `filtered_terms = ...` line gives a `TypeError: Expr.as_coefficient() missing 1 required positional argument: 'expr'` error message when running your code.

Comment: I modified my code This should now correctly filter out terms

Comment: Strange, but it still gives an error at the very same line, but this time it says `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType'...